# How can you guarantee quicksort will sort an array of integers?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, quicksort, integer

Got asked this in a lecture...stumped by it a bit.

how can you guarantee that quicksort will always sort an array of integers?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "how does one prove that quicksort works?"?

Comment: Check that the invariants hold

Comment: What do you mean by this?  Do you mean "why does quicksort work correctly," or "what changes would you need to make to ensure that you always sort integers correctly?"

Comment: Do you mean "how does one prove that quicksort works?"? is the answer I seek I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quicksort function by taking a pivot value, and sorting the remaining data in to two groups. One higher and one lower. You then do this to the each group in turn until you get groups no larger than one. At this point you can guarantee that the data is sorted because you can guarantee that any pivot value is in the correct place because you have directly compared it with another pivot value, which is also in the correct place. In the end, you are left with sets of size 1 or size 0 which cannot be sorted because they cannot be rearranged and thus are already sorted.

Hope this helps, it was what we were taught for A Level Further Mathematics (16-18, UK).

Answer (score 3):

Gratuitously plagiarising [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort):

> The correctness of the partition algorithm is based on the following
> two arguments:
>
> - At each iteration, all the elements processed so far
>   are in the desired position: before the pivot if less than the pivot's
>   value, after the pivot if greater than the pivot's value (loop
>   invariant).
> - Each iteration leaves one fewer element to be processed
>   (loop variant).
>
> The correctness of the overall algorithm can be proven
> via induction: for zero or one element, the algorithm leaves the data
> unchanged; for a larger data set it produces the concatenation of two
> parts, elements less than the pivot and elements greater than it,
> themselves sorted by the recursive hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Your professor may be referring to "stability." Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability.   Stable sorting algorithms maintain the relative order of records with equal keys. If all keys are different then this distinction is not necessary.

Quicksort (in efficient implementations) is not a stable sort, so one way to guarantee stability would be to insure that there are no duplicate integers in your array.